# How to implement a comparison logic into a set property of an array

Tags: c#, arrays, data-structures, properties

```
int maxHeight;
int minHeight;

public int [ , ] Heights
{
    get;
    set
    {
      if(value > maxHeight)
      {
        print("Max Height Changed !");
      }   

      if(value < minHeight)
      {
        print("Min Height Changed !");
      }
    }
}
```

I want to implement an immediate comparison logic for array values when the value in an index changed. If the new value is greater than the recent max value, or lesser than the recent smallest value it must be prompted. However I couldn't find a way to implement it directly into a set property without creating a custom method.

Comment: _However I couldn't find a way to implement it directly into a set property_ - can you elaborate, what is specific issue, why think you can not implement it inside `setter`? Notice that `value` and `maxHeight` variables are different types

Comment: @Fabio instead of setting the array as private and changing its values via a public Setter method (not property) and doing the min-max comparison inside of that mehod; implementing that functionality into a setter property would be more practical and elegant solution. And yes, I'm aware that value represent an array type, not an int. That code is just exemplary, however I couldn' find a way to both set and compare a value into an array in a setter prop

Comment: Setter is a method, you can do in setter same things you can do in method

Comment: Can you show, how this property be used in the code?

Comment: it is not to be used in any kind of unusual way. Just reach a value in a specific index or rewrite the data in an index. Question is now answered and it seems a desperate case. Thanks for your help mate.

Answer (score 0):

In a setter, `value` is the value that is to be set for the property. So in this case, `value` will be an `int[,]`, which cannot be directly compared to a single `int`. If you're wanting to capture the change of a value *within* the array, you can't do that with a setter on the array property itself. In other words, your setter will only be called when you set the value of the entire array property (even if you set it to the same array that it's already set tp).

In short, there's not a way to capture a change to a 2-D array. You'd have the *encapsulate* the array and implement your own indexers add custom logic to the setting of an indexed value.